SingalR not working on server IIS. works on local host
I have websockets enabled on my iis server. I am using singal R to update a progress bar during downloading. Works and local host but when published to server I get the following.
blazor.web.js:1  [2024-07-08T21:19:28.598Z] Error: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.

the full stack trace if needed
    blazor.web.js:1  [2024-07-08T21:19:28.598Z] Error: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.NegotiateAsync(Uri url, HttpClient httpClient, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.GetNegotiationResponseAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsyncCore(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsync(TransferFormat transferFormat, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncInner(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at SecureFileShare.Client.Components.ProgressUIComponent.OnInitializedAsync() in C:\BHIDEV22\WebDev\SecureFileShare\SecureFileShare.Client\Components\ProgressUIComponent.razor:line 70
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
log @ blazor.web.js:1
blazor.web.js:1 [2024-07-08T21:19:28.599Z] Information: Connection disconnected.
btest/:1  The file at 'http://bhub/btest/api/download' was loaded over an insecure connection. This file should be served over HTTPS.
blazor.web.js:1  Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.
    at Nn.send (blazor.web.js:1:85376)
    at gn._sendMessage (blazor.web.js:1:58807)
    at gn._sendWithProtocol (blazor.web.js:1:58897)
    at gn.send (blazor.web.js:1:59005)
    at Fo.beginInvokeDotNetFromJS (blazor.web.js:1:139654)
    at y.invokeDotNetMethodAsync (blazor.web.js:1:4322)
    at S.invokeMethodAsync (blazor.web.js:1:5830)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (blazor.bootstrap.js:445:30)
    at Object.trigger (event-handler.js:289:15)
    at modal.js:196:20

Line 70 is here with startAsync() which is where the connection can't be started I assume
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"), options =>
        {
            options.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        })
        .Build();

    _hubConnection.On<int>("ReceiveProgress", p =>
    {
        progress = p;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    });

    await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
}

here is my program cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


//For windows authentication 
//---------------------
//First add nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiat
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

//Inject IHttpContextAccessor
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

//injects
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserService>();
builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(
    ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<CircuitHandler, UserCircuitHandler>());
//

builder.Services.AddControllers();

//form file upload size
builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue; // Set an appropriate limit
});

//Enabling Kestrel Support for the Large Files
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
    serverOptions.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = long.MaxValue;
});


//bootstrap
builder.Services.AddBlazorBootstrap();

//Inject repo
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISfsEmailDetailRepo, SfsEmailDetailRepo>();

builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<SecureFileShareContext>(opt =>
    opt.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SecureFileShare"))
    );
//

//for signalR
builder.Services.AddSignalR();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameUserIdProvider>();

builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
{
    opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
        ["application/octet-stream"]);
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});


var app = builder.Build();

//for singalR
app.UseResponseCompression();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();

///
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
///

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(SecureFileShare.Client._Imports).Assembly);

app.MapControllers();

//SInglarR
app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");

app.Run();

my hub
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}

function in my download controller for updating my UI. Doubt this is needed but I believe I am missing something in authentication for program.cs. I am not sure why it is not loading as everything I see mentions websockets which are enabled.
private async Task AddFileToArchive(ZipArchive archive, string filePath, string entryName, long totalSize)
{
    var entry = archive.CreateEntry(entryName);

    using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[60000];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = await fileStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            await entryStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesWritten += bytesRead;

            int percentComplete = (int)((double)bytesWritten / totalSize * 100);
            await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveProgress", percentComplete);
        }
    }
}


Authentication tokens are not for delegation by default, so you cannot pass them on from one web app to another.

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 401 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

enabled failed stack trace, this error did not generate a log
found a long thread here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25000
it may work for some, but it didn't work for me. Same problem of once published the server fails connection and is unauthorized despite having a valid access token and user

Please refer to this link on how to enable failed request tracking: Using Failed Request Tracing. please make sure you enable failed request tracking in the website interface.
